# Angular repeat passing same element to ngClick parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm try set a function to the `ngClick` on the button in repeating, something like this:

```
<button data-ng-repeat="letter in ctrl.letters"
        data-ng-click="ctrl.selectLetter(letter)"
        data-ng-class="{'selected-letter' : ctrl.selectedLetter == letter }"
        style="width: 19%; float: left;" class="button">
    <span>{{letter}}</span>
</button>
```

Where `ctrl.etters` is an array `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', etc...]`, but when I click in the any button, is passing `'A'` to the event.

How to can I pass each array element in the click event parameter?

==================================================================

I created a `toLower` function just to test passing parameter:

```
<button data-ng-repeat="letter in ctrl.letters"
        data-ng-click="ctrl.selectLetter(letter)"
        data-ng-class="{'selected-letter' : ctrl.selectedLetter == letter }"
        style="width: 19%; float: left;" class="button">
    <span>{{ ctrl.toLower(letter) }}</span>
</button>
```

My `toLower` function:

```
this.toLower = functino toLower(letter) {
    return letter.toLowerCase();
};
```

So this test is printing for me lowercase letter, but I don't really know why in the click event is all time passing first Array element.

When I try `alert` parameter, is always alerting the letter `A`:

```
this.selectLetter = function selectLetter(letter) {
    alert(letter); // always alerting "A"
};
```

Comment: As you are already doing this `data-ng-click="ctrl.selectLetter(letter)"` it should pass current letter to `selectLetter` function(overall seems correct to me).. could you please plunkr/fiddle? does span display  correct `{{letter}}`?

Comment: I dont see any issues in the letters being passed.  http://codepen.io/jsreekanth/pen/RGmvKa everything looks good to me. Can you be more specific please?

Comment: I'm creating `jsbin` example to post here, but has not any issues too, I don't know why, I will restart my browser and clear cache to try again

Comment: Sorry for all! I found the problem, is because I putting ALL buttons in one `label`, so maybe when I click in the any button, I clicking same label, referencing the first button (button A). And I had not get attention in this point, so I has not putting the `label` tag in my example, sorry for all